# What operation on a C++ vector leads to assignment operator call?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I create `std::vector<MyClass> MyVector`, what operation on `MyVector` will lead to the assignment operator of `MyClass` call?

Comment: I believe that C++11 only requires such a type to be move-assignable. So which assignment operator are you talking about? Also, it might be helpful if you explained what problem you're trying to solve and/or provided some code to contextualize the question.

Comment: Isn't this meaningless without a declaration of `MyClass`? AFAIK which constructors/operators can be called depends on which are available vs which are deleted/private. Whether they _will_ be called also depends on what you do with the `vector`. What'll that be?

Comment: You could instrument your own move assignment and copy assignment operators on `MyClass` to find out!  (Assuming that you want info on both.) As pointed out by @underscore_d, it will also depend on whether or not you have move/copy ctors and move/copy assignment operators. E.g.  If you insert() and the vector must be expanded, vector will move all of the MyClass object to the new (larger) buffer; however, if no move is available, it will have to copy assign them.  The complete answer is probably STL implementation dependent.

Comment: @DavidThomas Great point, implementing all ctors/operators of interest with diagnostic `cout`s is _the_ way to test this practically and, in my experience, can lead to very interesting results. I was clearly thinking too literally for that at the moment!

Answer (score 3):

> the assignment operator of `MyClass`

is a somewhat ambiguous phrase.  There are two assignment operations that you might reasonably be referring to:

1. The move assignment.
2. The copy assignment.

Furthermore, if `MyClass` has no move assignment operator, then everything that requires `MyClass` to be move assignable will actually call `MyClass`'s copy assignment operator.

A more precise question might be a two-parter:

1. What operations of `std::vector<MyClass>` require `MyClass` to be move assignable?
2. What operations of `std::vector<MyClass>` require `MyClass` to be copy assignable?

If `MyClass` has both a move and copy assignment operator, then the first set will call the move assignment operator and the second set will call the copy assignment operator.

If `MyClass` only has a copy assignment operator, then *both sets* will call the copy assignment operator.

This answer will list these two sets separately.  And then you will have to interpret them for your *specific* `MyClass` as described above.  And as this answer is currently tagged with [c++11], I will answer according to the C++11 spec:  [N3290](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf).  For operations that require copy assignable, if they will also exercise a move assignment operator (if it exists), I don't bother listing that since a move assignable requirement is a subset of the copy assignable requirement.

**`std::vector<MyClass>` operations which require `MyClass` to be move assignable:**

```
template <class InputIterator>
    void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last); // when v = *first would call the move assignment operator
template <class... Args> iterator emplace(const_iterator position, Args&&... args);  // if args is not an lvalue value_type
iterator     insert(const_iterator position, value_type&& x);
template <class InputIterator>
iterator insert(const_iterator position,
                InputIterator first, InputIterator last);  // if value_type = *first does not call the copy assignment operator
iterator erase(const_iterator position);
iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
```

**`std::vector<MyClass>` operations which require `MyClass` to be copy assignable:**

```
vector& operator=(const vector& x);
vector& operator=(initializer_list<value_type>);
template <class InputIterator>
    void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last); // when v = *first would call the copy assignment operator
void assign(size_type n, const value_type& u);
void assign(initializer_list<value_type>);
template <class... Args> iterator emplace(const_iterator position, Args&&... args);  // if args is an lvalue value_type
iterator insert(const_iterator position, const value_type& x);
iterator insert(const_iterator position,
                InputIterator first, InputIterator last);  // if value_type = *first does call the copy assignment operator
iterator insert(const_iterator position, initializer_list<value_type> il);
```

Also, be aware that this answer pedantically answers the case for `std::vector<MyClass>` (as asked).  For some custom allocators, the `vector`'s move assignment operator can involve a requirement for the `value_type` to be move assignable.  Indeed, to be really pedantic, the C++11 `std::allocator` actually *did* require this, but that was largely seen as a defect to [N3290](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) and [was subsequently fixed](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2103).  So I include that fix in my report.  However if you don't want to include that fix, then C++11's `vector& operator=(vector&& x);` requires `value_type` to be move assignable too.